# Android: MediaPlayer Play, Pause, Resume audio file like WhatsApp

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I'm working on one project, I tried to play audio files like WhatsApp.
suppose three files in a row sent by the user, ** I want to play/pause/resume audio file exactly like WhatsApp** -

**what I want to do:**

if I clicked on the first audio file (play button) it should start playing if I clicked on pause it should stop and if I clicked on play again it should start playing from exactly where we paused(resume audio file).

other scenarios would be if the first file is playing and I clicked on the second file, the first file should stop playing(rather say pause) and the second file should start playing the second audio file, and if I clicked on play of third file second file should pause and the third audio file should start playing. and if I click play on first file third file should pause and the first file should resume playing.

**what done by me:**
I'm using MediaPlayer to play the audio file in recylerview. I can play and pause files but I fail to resume file after a pause(how to store the last position of each file) and when my first file playing and I clicked on second file both file continue playing rather than the recent one.

**tried:** I tried to find out this on the stack but there are lots of questions like on play pause and resume none of them help me to solve my problem half of the questions unanswered and half of the users no longer using stack overflow(last seen).

**my question:** how to resume each file after a pause, how to save the last position?

code:
I'm using MVVM architecture and my code written in one of the view holders.

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.audio_play_button:
                mAudioPauseButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mAudioPlayButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                play();
                break;
            case R.id.audio_pause_button:
                mAudioPauseButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mAudioPlayButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pause();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

i'm using two icons for play pause and handle visibility **on click**.

```
 private void play() {

        if (mMediaPlayer == null) {
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            setAudioUrltoMediaPlayer();

        } else {
            if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mMediaPlayer.pause();
            } else {
                    setAudioUrltoMediaPlayer();
            }
        }

        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                if (mMediaPlayer != null) {

                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                    totalTime = mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
                    mTextChatAudioTime.setText(millisecondsToString(totalTime));
                    mAudioSeekBar.setProgress(0);
                    mAudioSeekBar.setMax(totalTime);
                    mAudioSeekBar.setClickable(true);

                    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mAudioSeekBar.setProgress(mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                        }
                    }, 0, 200);

                    mAudioSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                        @Override
                        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                            if (fromUser) {
                                mMediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                            }
                            final long mMinutes = (progress / 1000) / 60;//converting into minutes
                            final int mSeconds = ((progress / 1000) % 60);//converting into seconds
                            mTextChatAudioTime.setText(mMinutes + ":" + mSeconds);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                            int CurrentLevel = mAudioSeekBar.getProgress();
                            if (CurrentLevel < 30)
                                CurrentLevel = 30;
                            mAudioSeekBar.setProgress(CurrentLevel);
                        }
                    });

                    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            final Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    mAudioPauseButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    mAudioPlayButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    mMediaPlayer.stop();

                                }
                            }, 200);
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void setAudioUrltoMediaPlayer() {
        if (setAudioUrl != null) {
            Log.d("audio file", "available" + setAudioUrl);
            try {
                Log.d("setAudioUrl", ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + setAudioUrl);
                mMediaPlayer.reset();
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(setAudioUrl);
                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                mMediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
                mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("audio file", "available" + setAudioUrl);
        }
    }

    private void pause() {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                //lastposition = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                mMediaPlayer.pause();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you want to save multiple files of state or a single one?

Comment: i already save audio files in my project folder and i'm directly playing that file by setting uri in setdatasource and each audio file is successfully playing on click of play.

Comment: if you are asking about position then i want to save all files last position

Comment: What do you use for playing the audio file?

Comment: i'm using MediaPlayer

Comment: Are you playing in recyclerview?

Comment: yes i'm playing audio files in recyclerview

Comment: Like [this](https://github.com/Krupen/AutoplayVideos) and [this](https://github.com/mobileappsvn/AutoPlayVideoRecyclerView)

Comment: i think no i cant find anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194379/discussion-between-rucha-bhatt-joshi-and-piyush-gupta).

Comment: @RuchaBhattJoshi Don't simply tag unnecessary tags.

Comment: @kiran whats wrong in whatsapp tag i want to implement functionality like that its easy to find when someone wants to help

Comment: @RuchaBhattJoshi Well `Whatsapp` tag is to ask question related to `whatsapp`, also are you sure that they will be using `android mediaplayer` to have playback feature? They might have their own playback engine. Which is, your question is purely related to `android mediaplayer` you can have description like `I want whatsap kinda feature` in question.

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't know what they are using i'm talking here about functionality which i want to achieve by using MediaPlayer, may be if i write something like whatsapp they can check on their mobile if there's lack in my explanation about functionality. well, you already remove the tag so no point. i'll be glad if you help me to solve this problem rather correcting my tags. thank you in advance.

Comment: @RuchaBhattJoshi I can help you debug your issue, provided complete code which I will compile to my mobile and run. (link to `zip` file should do)

Comment: @RuchaBhattJoshi Let me know if my understanding is correct. As of now what you have is an implementation which is capable of playing/pausing single file upon user event, this you want to extend which is capable of playing multiple files such that upon clicking on particular file again it should start playing from the last position.

Comment: i can not send you my code file due to privacy that you also know

Comment: I didn't down vote, perhaps you need to provide [mcve].

Comment: @kiranBiradar oh sorry, fine i will check this link and try to do

Comment: You have a recyclerview so you have a model. Then you can store last playing time. Say you are playing music A and its current time is 2.30. No you are playing music B. So you can get current playing time from **mediaPlayer** store it in your model and also store the state like Pause,Resume,Playing. So when you resume music A start music and seek to 2.30

Comment: I have tried the same thing a long time ago and finally comes the ending solution by arguing with the QA, that if one file is playing and click on the second one the first one is reset and played the second one... If you need this solution of mine please let me know. :P @RuchaBhattJoshi

Comment: @RuchaBhattJoshi and actually you cannot resume the old the file because the state is maintained by the MediaPlayer instance, so when you clicked on the second file it destroys the first instance and creates a new instance for the second one that's why You can't resume the old file.

Answer (score 2):

This is the [mediaplayer](https://github.com/dhananjayandroid/OAudioPlayer) I had written a few years back.

This has an option to play a playlist. It has Play, Pause, Next, Prev buttons and their actions too.

You can modify the app as per your need.
You can show your playlist in a recyclerview and then on item click you can send the item as a broadcast to play.

Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score -1):

You can store the position of currently running video.Then if you are playing another video, then stop the video of stored position and update the position.

For resuming video, You can store the running time of the video by having a parameter in your model file.You can resume the video from where you stop it.

Here is the description for resuming vdo

[How to stream a video to play from a particular time in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516657/how-to-stream-a-video-to-play-from-a-particular-time-in-android/8578715)

Comment: he is not talking about the video